# Getting data from strapi endpoints giving 404 error code

Tags: postman, http-status-code-404, strapi

I have created a collection in strapi named detail. Published the entries of collection. But still I am getting 404 error in postman.
[collection in strapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSuS6.png)
[checked draft and publish collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGlO3.png)
[published all entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awIay.png)
[still getting 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sr6X.png)

[I have set permission to find for public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjslZ.png)

Comment: Hello, can you share your code for your 404 error please? Where does this error come from? and When does this happen? Which request are you requesting? URL? Is the request URL valid? which endpoint are you asking?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check the URL in postman. You have two `enter` key characters at the trailing end of the URL. Rest of the configuration in `Strapi` seem correct. Remove those characters in postman and try again.